# I need a 301 redirect

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, url-routing, http-status-code-301

Can someone help me with a rule that will redirect any url that begins with someDomain/catalog/product_info.php and have it redirect to the site's homepage?

Comment: A rule for what? IIS? Apache? Some CMS? We can only help you if we know what your expectations are.

Comment: The server is apache on Unix

Comment: Then DopeGhoti answer is perfect for you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your site is e. g. `example.com` and you want to redirect a request for http://example.com/catalog/product_info.php to http://example.com, you can do this (for Apache):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^catalog/product_info\.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

Keep in mind that an HTTP/301 redirect is a 'Site Moved Permenantly'; if this is temporary, use a 302, or just silently rewrite the URL without redirecting the HTTP client (omit the `R=301` from the Rewrite Rule flags).